# Characteristic definition for higher order PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Given PDE $u_{x_1 x_2}-4u_{x_3 x_3}+u_{x_1}=0$ in the space where $x_1 \cos (\theta) + x_2 \sin (\theta)\ge0$. Where values of $u$ and its normal derivative are given on plane $x_1 \cos (\theta) + x_2 \sin (\theta)=0$. Question asks for what values of $\theta$ is the problem characteristic and what values of $\theta$ make it strictly hyperbolic?

I haven't encountered the word characteristic applied to 2nd-order PDEs before (unless they're factorable) and the only definition of strictly hyperbolic that I see is for systems of the form $u^{(i)}_t+\sum_jf^{(j)}_x=0$. So it looks like I should convert the PDE into a hyperbolic system, but it isn't clear to me how to do this unless I make $f=u_{x_i}$ but that doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer, to address the question about the meaning of
characteristic.
Let's say the pde is $f(u'',\nabla u,x) = 0$ where $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$,
$\nabla u$ is the gradient
and $u''$ the matrix of second derivatives, and $u$ and the normal
derivative of $u$ are specified on a smooth surface given implicitly as
$\phi(x)=0$, say
$$
    u(x) = g(x), \quad \nabla \phi \cdot \nabla u = h(x)
$$
 on the surface. For functions defined in the surface you can determine
directional derivatives in directions tangent to the surface
(by differentiating along curves in the surface).
Take two independent tangent vector fields to the surface,
$\tau=(\tau_1,\tau_2,\tau_3)$
and
$\tau'=(\tau_1',\tau_2',\tau_3')$
orthogonal to the normal field $\nabla\phi$
at each point (this is all local, they are defined in a neighborhood of some
given point in the surface). Then the given data are enough to determine
directional derivatives
$D_{\tau}g$, $D_{\tau'}g$, $D_{\tau}h$, and $D_{\tau'}h$. If we knew that
$u$ were defined in a neighborhood of the surface then these could be
expressed as
$$
 D_{\tau}g = \sum_{i=1}^3 \tau_{i}u_{x_i},
$$
$$
 D_{\tau}h
 =
 \sum_{i=1}^3 \tau_{i} \sum_k ( \phi_{x_i x_k}u_{x_k}+\phi_{x_k}u_{x_k x_i})
$$
and similarly for $D_{\tau'}$. (But these are not $\tau\cdot\nabla g$  or
$\tau\cdot\nabla h$
because $g$ and
$h$ are only defined on the surface, $\nabla g$ and $\nabla h$ are
meaningless.)

Note that you can find the first derivatives of $u$ on the surface because
the system of equations
$$
  \tau\cdot\nabla u = D_{\tau}g, \quad
  \tau'\cdot\nabla u = D_{\tau'}g, \quad
   \nabla\phi\cdot\nabla u = h
$$
has the invertible matrix  with rows $\tau$, $\ \tau'$, $\ \nabla\phi$.

Now, because
you have a second order equation, the
question is whether it is possible to also specify the second normal
derivative on the surface
$$
 s = \sum_{ik}\phi_{x_i}(\phi_{x_k}u_{x_k})_{x_i}
  =
 \sum_{ik}(\phi_{x_i}\phi_{x_k x_i}u_{x_k}+\phi_{x_i}\phi_{x_k}u_{x_k x_i}).
$$
The idea is that if you can't do this, then there is no hope of propagating
the Cauchy data off the surface.

To answer this, you have a system of 4 linear equations (they are linear
if the pde is quasilinear as in this case) to solve
for the 6 second derivatives of $u$ on the surface. The 4 equations are
the pde, the equation for $s$, and the two equations for $D_{\tau}h$ and
$D_{\tau'}h$. The coefficient matrix is 4 by 6. If the rank is less than
four, you could contrive functions $g$, $h$, and $s$ so that there is no
solution. So that is the question: is the rank 4? (I think it always
is for the given equation.)